# How to find and replace a string with a wildcard in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, replace

I'm new to all of this so take it easy on me. I'm trying to automate a process  where I change the port for a specific service. The port is determined in the file streamstack.exe.config. I have something that will find and replace a specific string within the file however in some situations I won't know the defined port number. Is it possible to find a string that contains a wildcard and replace with a predefined string? For example find `"localhost:.*"` and replace with `"localhost:80"`?

I have been able to use `findstr` with a `wildcard`, however I haven't been able to use some sort of replace with the output. I've also found something that will find a replace using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, however I cannot figure out how to use wildcard with it.

My code is:

```
@echo off

set "replace=localhost:.*"
set "replaced=localhost:80"

set "source=c:\blah\blah\streamstack.exe.config"
set "target=c:\blah\blah\streamstack1.exe.config"


setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %target%
endlocal
```

I was hoping it would locate the string that includes `localhost:` followed by any group of numbers representing the port, and replace with `localhost:80`, which is the port I need the service to be using.

Comment: Take a look at a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1174258/replace-a-string-with-wildcard-in-a-batch-file), hope you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any details about the format of the config file.

Assuming there is one name/value setting per line, and the order of the lines does ***not*** matter, then there is a very simple batch solution that is also very efficient. Use FINDSTR to write all lines *except* the localhost line, and then append your desired localhost line.

```
>"%target%" (findstr /v "^http://localhost:" "%source%" & echo http://localhost:80)
```

Of course the above will not work if the order of the lines is important.

You ought to check out my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is very powerful, yet simple to use. It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Using the same find/replace you used in PowerShell, the JREPL solution would be

```
call jrepl "(http://localhost):.*" "$1:80" /f "%source%" /o "%target%"
```

I used a regular expression capture group to save a bit of typing.

JREPL has loads of options, and full documentation is built-in to the utility. Use `jrepl /?help` to get a description of all the types of help that are available.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route and call on powershell instead of trying to get all of this done in a bat file.

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\David\Desktop\streamstack.exe.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ - 
replace "http://localhost:.*/", "http://localhost:80/" } | Set-Content 
c:\blah\blah\streamstack.exe.config
```

This seems to do the job, and I am able to execute it from within a bat using...

```
powershell -executionPolicy bypass -noexit -file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to replace the port number in a URL I extended the search string a bit in order to include the leading `://` after the protocol definition `http` or `https` and before the host name, and the trailing `/` after the port number (this also complies with [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744403)).

The following script replaces the port number only in the first occurrence of the desired URL, which is found when a string like `://` plus the given host name plus `:` plus a purely numeric port number plus `/` is encountered:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=c:\blah\blah\streamstack.exe.config" & rem // (original file)
set "_TARGET=c:\blah\blah\streamstack.exe.config" & rem // (modified file)
set "_TEMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"              & rem // (temporary file)
set "_HOST=localhost"                             & rem // (host name)
set "_PORT=80"                                    & rem // (new port name)

rem // Define to write to console if no target file is given:
if not defined _TARGET set "_TEMP=con"

rem // Store line-feed in variable:
(set ^"_LF=^
%= blank line =%
^")

rem // Write output to temporary file:
> "%_TEMP%" (
    rem // Read source file line by line, precede each line by line number plus `:`:
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_SOURCE%"') do (
        rem // Store currently iterated line, reset buffer for part left to host name:
        set "LINE=%%L" & set "LEFT="
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Get line portion right to `://` + host name + `:`:
        set "RIGHT=!LINE:*://%_HOST%:=!"
        rem // Check whether host name part has really been found:
        if not "!LINE!" == "!RIGHT!" (
            rem /* Buffer right line portion in a `for` variable
            rem    to transport it over the `endlocal` barrier: */
            for /F "delims=" %%J in (^""!RIGHT!"^") do (
                rem // Replace `://` + host name + `:` by a line-feed:
                for /F "delims=" %%I in (^"!LINE:://%_HOST%:^=^%_LF%%_LF%!^") do (
                    rem /* Ensure to only process first line of multi-line string
                    rem    to get the line portion left to `://`+ host name + `:`: */
                    if not defined LEFT (
                        endlocal
                        rem /* Store line portion left to `://` + host name + `:`,
                        rem    restore right line portion from `for` variable: */
                        set "LEFT=%%I" & set "RIGHT=%%~J"
                        rem /* Split off everything behind the first `/`, which
                        rem    constitutes the port number: */
                        for /F "delims=/" %%F in ("0%%~J") do (
                            rem /* Check whether port number is purely numeric;
                            rem    this is done by checking whether a `for /F` loop
                            rem    iterates if numerals are defined as delimiters: */
                            for /F "delims=0123456789" %%E in ("%%F") do rem/
                        ) && (
                            rem // `for /F` loop iterated, hence keep current line:
                            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        ) || (
                            rem // `for /F` loop did not iterate, change port number:
                            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            set "LINE=!LEFT!://%_HOST%:%_PORT%/!RIGHT:*/=!"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Return line string:
        echo(!LINE:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
)
rem /* Move temporary file onto target file;
rem    this allows source and target files to be identical: */
if defined _TARGET > nul move /Y "%_TEMP%" "%_TARGET%"

endlocal
exit /B
```